# How to fix www subdomain in cloudflare withe names.co.uk as a provider?

Tags: wordpress, dns, cloudflare

So i bought a domain from names.co.uk (yolsh.co.uk). And ive been attempting to attach it to my website. I changed the name servers to cloud flare and tried adding an a record to point to my website from www but when i checked it in my browser the url ([www.yolsh.co.uk](http://www.yolsh.co.uk)) is still resolving to the names.co.uk page and not to my website. I checked and my name servers seem to have propogated but it still isnt connecting to my website. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a question for their customer support team :)

Comment: Yeah i tried but they reconed that it wasnt their fault so they couldnt do anything

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question where you are creating the A records for pointing the domain to your R2(assuming again that you are storing the site content here on cloudflare).

Just follow these steps:

1. Look up the domain at: https://lookup.icann.org/en
2. When I checked, it's pointing correctly to the NS records of cloudflare.
3. Open https://dash.cloudflare.com/ and navigate to your site from the left pane by clicking on Websites.
4. Then from the left pane, click on DNS -> Records.
5. Create an A record and point it to wordpress.
6. If hosted on R2, then you need to go to R2 and then bucket settings and in that connect the custom domains.

Comment: Really sorry, i forgot to mention its on a cloudflare tunnel so i am using cname records pointing to that. Its hosted onnmy own server so i dont use r2. Could there be some setting in windows server that needs to be changed to allow a cloudflare tunnel